idiomatic way to Test if a `range` contains another `range`
This imho idiomatic test case doesn't compile:
#[test]
fn test_rangyness() {
    let a = 0..42;
    let b = 1..41;
    assert!(a.contains(&b)); // compiler error
}

I could do
#[test]
fn test_rangyness() {
    let a = 0..42;
    let b = 1..42;
    assert!(a.contains(&b.start) && a.contains(&b.end - 1));
}

but there is this ugly - 1 there that is necessary for correctness. Is there a more idiomatic way to test for this?

Does it feel any better as assert!(a.start <= b.start && a.end >= b.end) ?

It's trivial when both ranges are the same kind, but it becomes an interesting demand when we consider the more general case of comparing different range types (e.g. RangeInclusive and RangeTo). A method on RangeBounds would be useful IMO.

You can get rid of the -1 with an inclusive range: let b = 1..=41; and then assert!(a.contains(&b.start) && a.contains(&b.end));

This ContainsRange trait stretches the definition of idiomatic, and requires nightly Rust for the Step trait, but covers all RangeBounds<T: Step>. Solutions for stable Rust and RangeBounds<f32> are included too.
#![feature(step_trait)]

use std::iter::Step;
use std::ops::{Bound, RangeBounds};

trait ContainsRange<T> {
    fn contains_range(&self, other: &impl RangeBounds<T>) -> bool;
}

impl<T: Step, R: RangeBounds<T>> ContainsRange<T> for R {
    fn contains_range(&self, other: &impl RangeBounds<T>) -> bool {
        fn check<T: Step>(left: Bound<&T>, right: Bound<&T>, end: bool) -> bool {
            match (left, right, end) {
                (Bound::Unbounded, _, false) | (_, Bound::Unbounded, true) => true,
                (_, Bound::Unbounded, false) | (Bound::Unbounded, _, true) => false,
                (Bound::Included(l), Bound::Included(r), _)
                | (Bound::Excluded(l), Bound::Excluded(r), _) => l <= r,
                (Bound::Excluded(l), Bound::Included(r), false)
                | (Bound::Included(l), Bound::Excluded(r), true) => l < r,
                (Bound::Included(l), Bound::Excluded(r), false)
                | (Bound::Excluded(l), Bound::Included(r), true) => {
                    l <= r || l == &Step::forward(r.clone(), 1)
                }
            }
        }
        check(self.start_bound(), other.start_bound(), false)
            && check(other.end_bound(), self.end_bound(), true)
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_rangyness() {
    let a = 0..42;
    let b = 1..41;
    assert!(a.contains_range(&b));

    fn bound_permutations(x: i8) -> impl Iterator<Item = Bound<i8>> {
        [Bound::Unbounded, Bound::Included(x), Bound::Excluded(x)].into_iter()
    }
    fn effective_bound(b: Bound<i8>, end: bool) -> i8 {
        match (b, end) {
            (Bound::Included(x), _) => x,
            (Bound::Excluded(x), false) => x + 1,
            (Bound::Excluded(x), true) => x - 1,
            (Bound::Unbounded, false) => i8::MIN,
            (Bound::Unbounded, true) => i8::MAX,
        }
    }
    use itertools::Itertools;
    for permutation in (-3..=3).permutations(4) {
        for a in bound_permutations(permutation[0]) {
            for b in bound_permutations(permutation[1]) {
                for c in bound_permutations(permutation[2]) {
                    for d in bound_permutations(permutation[3]) {
                        let left = (a, b);
                        let right = (c, d);

                        let expected = effective_bound(a, false) <= effective_bound(c, false)
                            && effective_bound(b, true) >= effective_bound(d, true);
                        let actual = left.contains_range(&right);

                        assert_eq!(expected, actual, "{a:?} {b:?} - {c:?} {d:?}");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

If you're wondering, the Step trait is necessary to generically handle cases like this (inclusive 2 is promoted to exclusive 3 for purpose of comparison):
assert!((1..=2).contains_range(&(1..3)));

If you wanted to translate this solution to stable Rust (or floating-point types), you could implement a StableStep trait on the types you use:
trait StableStep: PartialOrd {
    fn forward(&self) -> Self;
}

impl StableStep for i8 {
    fn forward(&self) -> Self {
        *self + 1
    }
}

impl StableStep for f32 {
    fn forward(&self) -> Self {
        // Also nightly-only but you could copy the implementation into stable code.
        self.next_up()
    }
}

Then replace the Step bounds with StableStep and Step::forward(r.clone(), 1) with r.forward().

This wouldn't work for floating point ranges, since Step is not implemented for them. Upvoted for partial credit nonetheless.

@cyqsimon You are right, although half-way through my answer, I hint at how to support floats. I guess I'll note the limitation earlier in the answer, and possibly give an explicit blueprint for floats :)
